# When writing to files, it writes the same integers instead of different integers

Tags: java, for-loop, file-io, random

If you need any explanation, please feel free to ask. 
The objective of the EquationsAndAnswers class is to generate 8 arrays, 4 of string type, and 4 of double type and populate them with addition equations, then answers and so on for each basic mathematic operator. Then, from these 8 arrays, it **should** randomly select equations, one at a time, from any of the four string type equation arrays. After selecting the random equations and corresponding answers to be written, it writes them to the file(equations.txt). 
My problem is that after I call the writeBoth method from the Menu class, the equations.txt file looks like this:

```
6 + 10

6 + 10

8 - 9

8 - 9

6 + 10

8 - 9

6 + 10
```

rather than like this:

```
1+2

3-2

4*5

10÷2
```

My class Menu:

```
public class Menu {

    public static boolean additionBool = true;
    public static boolean subtractionBool = true;
    public static boolean multiplicationBool = true;
    public static boolean divisionBool = true;
    public static boolean doubleDigitBool = false;

    new EquationsAndAnswers().writeBoth();  
}
```

My class EquationsAndAnswers:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class EquationsAndAnswers {
/*Random Generators*/
    Random singleDigitNaturalGen = new Random();
    Random randomEquationPicker = new Random();
    Random doubleDigitNaturalGen = new Random();
public void writeBoth(){    



    /*Declaration of Four Basic Mathematic Operation Equation Arrays and Corresponding Answers*/
    String additionArrayEquation[] = new String[100];
    int additionArrayAnswers[] = new int[100];

    String subtractionArrayEquation[] = new String[100];
    int subtractionArrayAnswers[] = new int[100];

    String multiplicationArrayEquation[] = new String[100];
    int multiplicationArrayAnswers[] = new int[100];

    String divisionArrayEquation[] = new String[100];
    double divisionArrayAnswers[] = new double[100];

    String assortedEquations[] = new String[100];
    double assortedAnswers[] = new double[100];

    /*Population of Basic Operation Equation Arrays*/
    /*Population of Addition Equation and Answer Arrays*/
    for(int additionArrayGenerationX = 0; additionArrayGenerationX < additionArrayEquation.length; additionArrayGenerationX++){

        int tempAdditionY = singleDigitNaturalGen.nextInt(11), tempAdditionX = singleDigitNaturalGen.nextInt(11);
        int answer = tempAdditionY + tempAdditionX;
        String equation = (tempAdditionY + " + " + tempAdditionX); 
        additionArrayEquation[additionArrayGenerationX] = equation;
        additionArrayAnswers[additionArrayGenerationX] = answer;
    }



    /*Population of Subtraction Equation and Answer Arrays*/
    for(int subtractionArrayGenerationX = 0; subtractionArrayGenerationX < subtractionArrayEquation.length; subtractionArrayGenerationX++){

        int tempSubtractionY = singleDigitNaturalGen.nextInt(11), tempSubtractionX = singleDigitNaturalGen.nextInt(11);
        int answer = tempSubtractionY - tempSubtractionX;
        String equation = (tempSubtractionY + " - " + tempSubtractionX); 
        subtractionArrayEquation[subtractionArrayGenerationX] = equation;

        subtractionArrayAnswers[subtractionArrayGenerationX] = answer;
    }


    /*Population of Multiplication Equation and Answer Arrays*/
    for(int multiplicationArrayGenerationX = 0; multiplicationArrayGenerationX < multiplicationArrayEquation.length; multiplicationArrayGenerationX++){

        int tempMultiplicationY = singleDigitNaturalGen.nextInt(11), tempMultiplicationX = singleDigitNaturalGen.nextInt(11);
        int answer = tempMultiplicationY*tempMultiplicationX;
        String equation = ""; 
        multiplicationArrayEquation[multiplicationArrayGenerationX] = equation;

        multiplicationArrayAnswers[multiplicationArrayGenerationX] = answer;
    }



    /*Population of Division Equation and Answer Arrays*/
    for(int divisionArrayGenerationX = 0; divisionArrayGenerationX < divisionArrayEquation.length; divisionArrayGenerationX++){

        int tempDivisionY = singleDigitNaturalGen.nextInt(11), tempDivisionX = singleDigitNaturalGen.nextInt(11);
        double answer = ((double)tempDivisionY / (double)tempDivisionX);
        String equation = ""; 
        divisionArrayEquation[divisionArrayGenerationX] = equation;

        divisionArrayAnswers[divisionArrayGenerationX] = answer;
    }



    /*Deciding on Equations to be displayed.*/
    int i = 0;

    System.out.println(additionArrayEquation[0]);//dev

    /*This puts the equations in a random order in the assortedEquations array, in preparation to be written to the Equations.txt file*/        
    for(int epsilon = 0; epsilon < assortedEquations.length; epsilon++){    

        int equationType = randomEquationPicker.nextInt(4);

        if(equationType == 0){
            if(Menu.additionBool = true){
                assortedEquations[epsilon] = additionArrayEquation[i];
                assortedAnswers[epsilon] = additionArrayAnswers[i];
            }
            else{
                assortedEquations[epsilon] = "Bonus: Enter 0";
            }
        }

        else if(equationType == 1){
            if(Menu.subtractionBool = true){
                assortedEquations[epsilon] = subtractionArrayEquation[i];
                assortedAnswers[epsilon] = subtractionArrayAnswers[i];
            }

            else{
                assortedEquations[epsilon] = "Bonus: Enter 0";
            }
        }
        else if(equationType == 2){
            if(Menu.multiplicationBool = true){         
                assortedEquations[epsilon] = multiplicationArrayEquation[i];
                assortedAnswers[epsilon] = multiplicationArrayAnswers[i];
            }
            else{
                assortedEquations[epsilon] = "Bonus: Enter 0";
            }
        }   
        else{
            if(Menu.divisionBool = true){
                assortedEquations[epsilon] = divisionArrayEquation[i];
                assortedAnswers[epsilon] = divisionArrayAnswers[i];
            }
            else{
                assortedEquations[epsilon] = "Bonus: Enter 0";
            }
        }
    }


    /*Writing each equation to the file.*/
    try {
        BufferedWriter writeEquation = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Equations.txt"));
        BufferedWriter writeAnswer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Answers.txt"));

        for(int theta = 0; theta < assortedEquations.length; theta++){
            writeEquation.write(assortedEquations[theta]+ "\n");
            writeAnswer.write(assortedAnswers[theta] + "\n");
        }



        writeEquation.close();
        writeAnswer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Whoops, there seems to have been an error. Sorry about that.");}
}
}
```

Comment: `"If you need any explanation, please feel free to ask..."` -- yes, please explain your code and your problem. The details do matter.

Comment: I added a bit more detail about what my code does, I can't explain the problem any better because I don't know why I'm encountering it. Sorry.

Comment: I'll remove my down-vote for the additional information, and hopefully you'll get a decent answer soon, but as for me, I'm going to wait for more information including more detailed explanation of your current code including what the methods are supposed to do. Also what have your attempts to debug the code, including using a debugger, shown you?

Comment: I've tried commenting out the portion where it randomly selects equations to be added to the assortedEquations array, and just printing each individual array of equations and answers and the equations and answers seem to work fine so it has to be somewhere within the block of code starting at the comment "/*This puts the equations in a random order in the assortedEquations array, in preparation to be written to the Equations.txt file*/". Also, I've removed a good portion of my code that I deemed useless since it was the same thing only with double digits, which I wasn't using yet anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. My old code read:

```
int tempDivisionY = singleDigitNaturalGen.nextInt(11), tempDivisionX = singleDigitNaturalGen.nextInt(11);
double answer = ((double)tempDivisionY / (double)tempDivisionX);
String equation = "";
```

when it should've said:

```
String equation = tempDivisionY + " / " + tempDivisionX;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without running this I assume you're getting just `"Bonus: Enter 0"`?

```
if(Menu.subtractionBool = true)
if(Menu.subtractionBool == true)
```

There is a world of difference between those two lines.

Comment: And regardless, it's always better to do, `if (Menu.subtractionBool)`

Comment: I changed my conditions to read: "Menu.subtractionBool" for good practice, but that didn't change anything in the equations.txt file. Thanks for the suggestion.